# My AlarmManager not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, alarmmanager

I try every code which I got from Stackoverflow or from anywhere, but not getting success in `AlarmManager`, my `BroadcastReceiver` not even getting called. Here is my code:

```
    //My AlarmManager is in MyDB.Class extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

                System.out.println("Inside AlarmManager");
                // Create alarm manager
                AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                System.out.println("Inside alarmMgr0     " + alarmMgr0);

                // Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier
                // class
                Intent intent0 = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReciever.class);
                intent0.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent0.putExtra("req_code", v); // pI);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        mContext, v, intent0, 0);
                System.out.println("Inside pendingIntent0     "
                        + pendingIntent0);

                // set timer you want alarm to work
                Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
                timeOff9.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, scheduleDao1.getMeetingDay());
                System.out.println("Inside if getDay    "
                        + scheduleDao1.getDay());
                timeOff9.set(Calendar.MONTH, scheduleDao1.getMeetingMonth());
                System.out.println("Inside if getMonth    "
                        + scheduleDao1.getMonth());
                timeOff9.set(Calendar.YEAR, scheduleDao1.getMeetingYear());
                System.out.println("Inside if getYear    "
                        + scheduleDao1.getYear());

                if (scheduleDao1.getFromTimeHr() != 00) {
                    System.out.println("Inside if getFromTimeHr    "
                            + (scheduleDao1.getFromTimeHr() - 1));

                    timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
                            scheduleDao1.getFromTimeHr() - 1);
                }
                timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE,
                        scheduleDao1.getFromTimeMin());
                System.out.println("Inside getMeetingFromTimeMin     "
                        + scheduleDao1.getFromTimeMin());
                timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                // set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
                alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent0);

                contents.put(ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, v);

                //}
```

My Receiver class is here (Which is not get even called)

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mContext;
    int request_code = 0;

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mContext = context;
        System.out.println("Inside onReceive");
        mContext = context;
        request_code = intent.getIntExtra("req_code", 0);
        System.out.println("Inside request_code       " + request_code);

//      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
//      request_code = extras.getInt("req_code");
//      System.out.println("Inside request_code       " + request_code);

      }
}
```

And my Manifest code is like that....

```
.
.
.
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" 
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I didn't get what is going wrong with these code please someone help me here.

Comment: did you declare `AlarmReciever` in manifest?

Comment: you have to register broadcast receiver.

Comment: Yes @Amy i put all my code above with Manifest file where i mentioned AlarmReciever.

Comment: try to declare with fully qualified name

Comment: set the alarm time `System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000` and check if the receiver being called

Comment: Ok @rainash i try that.

Comment: no @rainash my Receiver class not even called. I think i made a mistake in AlarmManager class but i don't kw where exactly i am doing it.

Comment: I suggest you change the flag of `getBroadcast`, use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of 0

Comment: No @rainash these is not working for me. :(

Comment: another try is change the way of creating intent of Receiver, use `new Intent(Action)` instead, add the action in menifest, add the permission in menifest `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />`

Comment: @rainash can you please elaborate it, then how i called my BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89222/discussion-between-rainash-and-ulhas-patil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got What i want, with the help of @kgandroid & @rainash 
Here i post my Solve code now. which is working fine for me & Showing Notifications.
And i also able to set here **Multiple AlarmManager** with my required time.

```js
// Create alarm manager
   AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager) mContext
  .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    
  // Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier
    // class
  Intent intent0 = new Intent("alarm");
  intent0.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent0.putExtra("req_code", v); // pI);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent
    .getBroadcast(mContext, v, intent0,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  // set timer you want alarm to work
 Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
 timeOff9.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 timeOff9.set(scheduleDao1.getYear(),
  (scheduleDao1.getMonth()) - 1,  //Months start from '0'
  scheduleDao1.getDay(),
 (scheduleDao1.getFromTimeHr()) - 1,//I want those notification before 1hr
   scheduleDao1.getFromTimeMin(), 0);

 // long dateWeGet = Long.valueOf(dateString);
   // set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
  alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent0);

contents.put(ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, v);
```

Comment: what is `contents` here?

Comment: @ParagKadam ContentValue to store it in Database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    public void setAlarm1(long interval){

            /* info.setText("\n\n***\n"
                + "Alarm1 is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                + "***\n");*/

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),RQS_1, intent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager1 = ((ApplicationConstant)ListOfAds.this.getApplication()).getmanager();

             alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);   
            alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,interval, 60000, pendingIntent);

             System.out.println("Alarm fired ListofAds:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        }
```

The **AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <receiver
            android:name="yourpackagename.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:process=":remote" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Permissions:**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Try the above code.I am sure that the Alarm Manager will get called.

Comment: can you please tell how i set "long interval" in which format ? coz my AlarmManager not get called when i set it day,month, year & time in my way, is there any other way to set AlarmManager ?

Comment: INTERVAL = 30000; ...that is 30 s...try it and let me know

Comment: It works and in another attempt it didn't.
when i set System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000 it works only once, it called my Receiver class and show Notification as well but when i turn it to my code which is timeOff9.getTimeInMillis() it not even call my Receiver class at all.

Comment: Then there must be some problem in timeOff9

Comment: Yes @kgandroid i search lot about it, but all i see same code that's why i didn't find out my problem.

Comment: Make sure that your timeOff9 has a valid value...the above code is working for sure...you just have to modify it according to your requirement

Comment: my log for timeOff9 is  **Inside timeOff9.getTimeInMillis()     1445327100840**

Comment: Oh god..!! that was the reason why your alarm is not firing...convert  1445327100840  millis to day and you will see  1445327100840  millis is 16728 days approx....hence your alarm will fire after 16728 days...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89237/discussion-between-kgandroid-and-ulhas-patil).