# BroadcastReceiver is not being fired by AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

Here is my code below, what is the problem? If i look at log, there is no start of AlarmReceiver class. So no notification is sent to user. I tried every minute in loop  and still nothing happened. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance!!

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm(int hour, int min)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

//Receiver Class  AlarmReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    taskDb = new TaskDb(context);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    String temp ="";
    for(String s: taskDb.selectTodayTasks())
    {
        temp +="-" + s + "\n";
    }

    if(!temp.equals("")) {
        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.today_tasks))
                .setContentText(temp)
                .setLights(Color.CYAN,500,500)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
    }

}
```

//android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".background.AlarmReceiver"  android:enabled="true">
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you registered it in manifest??

Comment: @kgandroid yes i did

Comment: I have posted a same answer today.Have a look at it.It is a working soln. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493754/my-alarmmanager-not-getting-called/32494667#32494667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `PendingIntent.getService` to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

Because [PendingIntent.getService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) is used to *Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a service,...* but [PendingIntent.getBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) for `Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast,...`

Comment: Thank you.. But it just blinks now, there is no text =(

Comment: @MertSerimer: `BroadcastReceiver` time is very less to try it as : Start a IntentService from `onReceive` then do all task related to `notification` in it.

Comment: so i will start a new activity and call notification there? like startactivity?

Comment: @MertSerimer: Yes do same work  in IntentServicw which is currently doing in onReceive method